# sending object converted to json string with post to php script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, object

Right, so need some help with why it doesn't do what I want it to do.

I have something like this

```
    var getUsername = $("username").val();
    var getPassword = $("password").val();
    var getEmail = $("email").val();

    var obj =
    {
        "register": 1,
        "username": getUsername,
        "password": getPassword,
        "email": getEmail
    };

    var newObj = JSON.stringify(obj);

    $.post("authentication.php", { "obj": newObj },
        function(data){ //etcetc
```

Now, when it actually posts the object to the PHP script the only thing it sends is

`obj:{"register":1}`

The rest of the vars just disappears somewhere.

Well then I console.log and see that the stringified object only actually contains "register" and nothing else. So I'm dumb and doing something wrong, and would gladly love some help.

Comment: What is username, password and email. Are they ID attributes or class attributes of the HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selectors you are using are not specifying whether you are looking for ids, classes etc. Therefore they can't be found and so have no value. If username, etc are ids then you would do the following:

In html:

```
<input type="text" id="username" />
```

in javascript:

```
var getUsername = $("#username").val();
    var getPassword = $("#password").val();
    var getEmail = $("#email").val();
```

Comment: As expected, I was being dumb (and frustrated), so obvious when someone points it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The things wrong in your piece of code are,

1. You **didn't mention the type of the attributes** passed for getting the value. For example, if you need value of a textbox with Id "username", use `$("#username").val();`
2. **No need to create a new Object called "obj"** within `$.post()`. Just pass the 'newObj' directly. This is not an error but i prefer this to be a good practice.